# rewrite Vitual file with pillow image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am developing a python site with flask, pyqrcode and pillow to generate qrcode. But when I want to add a logo to my qrcode, I go through a virtual file but I can't rewrite over it (after paste logo) after creating it for the qrcode generation.

```
with io.BytesIO() as virtual_file:
     qr.png(file=virtual_file, scale=int(scales), module_color=color_hex, background=color_bg_hex, quiet_zone=int(self.quiet_zone))
     #ajout logo dans le qrcode créé
     if self.picture is not None :
           qrcode = Image.open(virtual_file)
           bord = self.scale * self.quiet_zone
           position = ((qrcode.width - self.picture.width - bord), (qrcode.height - self.picture.height - bord))
 qrcode.paste(self.picture, position)
           virtual_file = open(virtual_file, "wb")
           virtual_file = io.BytesIO(qrcode)
     image_as_str = base64.b64encode(virtual_file.getvalue()).decode("ascii")        
     return image_as_str
```

Answer (score 0):

With pillow, you have to read the file then load it in memory before closing the file.

Try this :

```
from PIL import Image
import io
import base64

with io.BytesIO() as virtual_file:
    qr.png(file=virtual_file, scale=int(scales), module_color=color_hex, background=color_bg_hex, quiet_zone=int(self.quiet_zone))
    img_qr = Image.open(virtual_file)
    img_qr.load()
```

Then you can work with the img_qr.

To convert to base64 at the end (I think there is a better way) :

```
virtual_file= io.BytesIO()
img_qr.save(virtual_file, format="PNG")
myimage = virtual_file.getvalue()
image_as_str = base64.b64encode(myimage).decode("ascii")
```